# vim issue with tab/space in multi-line abbreviations in vimrc

Tags: vim, vimrc

i am trying to write a vim abbreviation to create a template program in c

I have given the abbreviation as below in the .vimrc

```
abbr main #include<stdio.h>
\^M#include<string.h>
\^M#include<math.h>
\^M#include<stdlib.h>
\^M
\^Mint main() {
\^M int T, N;
\^M scanf("%d", &T);
\^M while(T-- > 0) {
\^M     scanf("%d", &N);
\^M }
\^M return 0;
\^M}
```

When I type the word `main`, the abbreviation is coming into effect, but it's not indented properly. 
I tried with just spaces/just tabs/combination but nothing gets the code indented perfectly.  Why?

[image: abbr distorted]

Any help?

Update: I tried with

```
 abbr main #include<stdio.h>
\<CR>#include<string.h>
\<CR>
\<CR>int main() {
\<CR>int T, N;
\<CR>scanf("%d", &T);
\<CR>while(T-- > 0) {
\<CR>scanf("%d", &N);
\<CR>}
\<CR>return 0;
\<CR>}
```

It leads to the same result. Can anyone please show me how to add a multi-line abbreviation with proper indentation?

Comment: isn't `^M`, window's newline character? is there a reason, you are having `\^M` instead of unix styled spaces?

Comment: Hi @Madhavan, if I didn't type that, then all the lines are getting cramped up in single line. Hence i added a new line by pressing `Ctrl + V` followed by `Enter` key.

Comment: why don't you try `\n` and for inner blocks, add an extra `\t` after newline char...  in emacs, `\n` and `\t` is what people use

Comment: @Madhavan Thanks for your reply. I tried with `\n`, but no success yet. All lines get cramped in single line.. : (

Answer (score 3):

Actually I think that your question is a [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem): I think that your actual problem isn't `How can I do a multiline abbreviation?` but `How can I easily add a sample function with a few keystrokes?`. And if you want to do that, you shouldn't use abbreviations but snippets.

**Why not an abbreviation?**

First let's take a look at [`:h abbreviations`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/map.html#Abbreviations):

> [abbreviations] can be used to save typing for often used long words.  And
>   you can use it to automatically correct obvious spelling errors.

Abbreviations are made for changes smaller than a whole function, it is simply not there goal. What you're trying to do is typically to create a snippet, and some **great** tools already exists so you don't have to reinvent the wheel.

**What is a snippet?**

To keep it clear and concise I'll quote [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snippet_(programming)):

> Snippet is a programming term for a small region of re-usable source code, machine code, or text.

**How do I get some snippets?**

First you need a repository of snippets. Of course you can manually create them one by one, but Vim has a cool community which has already struggled with your problem and solved it.

So [vim-snippets](https://github.com/honza/vim-snippets) is what you are looking for: With hundreds of snippets for more than 60 languages *(including a C main() function)* it is a great base to begin with. Of course you can add your own snippets if you find one is missing.

**How do I use these snippets?**

Now that you have your snippets, you need a snippet engine which will allow you to add them in your buffers. The readme of vim-snippets has [a section](https://github.com/honza/vim-snippets#snippet-engines-supporting-vim-snippets) dedicated to the supported engines.

I would recommand [ultisnips](https://github.com/sirver/ultisnips) but that is only a personnal matter and you should try the different engines suggested to see which one is your favorite.

**How do I get that?**

If you're using a [plugin manager](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/388/1841) it's pretty easy. For example with [vim-plug](https://github.com/junegunn/vim-plug) you simlpy add this line to your `.vimrc`:

```
Plug 'SirVer/ultisnips' | Plug 'honza/vim-snippets'
```

Then you can follow the basic configuration recommanded in the [ultisnips readme](https://github.com/sirver/ultisnips#quick-start):

```
let g:UltiSnipsExpandTrigger="<tab>"
let g:UltiSnipsJumpForwardTrigger="<c-b>"
let g:UltiSnipsJumpBackwardTrigger="<c-z>"
```

And after using `:PluginInstall` you can start to use your snippets with <kbd>tab</kbd>.

Comment: Also I think you might be interested in the [SE site dedicated to Vim](http://vi.stackexchange.com/) for your future questions about our beloved editor ;-)